# Directory access is forbidden error in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I tried to access a folder in localhost, I got:

> Directory access is forbidden. 403 forbidden

I had followed a tutorial for CodeIgniter.

So I deleted the `.htaccess` file, but still can't solve the problem.

Maybe the `httpd.conf` has some settings wrong?

Comment: Did you check permissions?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter